# CSS stylesheet for XML document + escaped tags

Tags: css, xml, html-escape-characters

I need xml-file to be displayed in a frame at my report HTML page, everything works fine, but it stops working when I add styles to my XML document? is there any way to display my xml-document with styles and tags at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

W3 recommends xslt which allows styling for xml documents, you can learn more here. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt

Comment: you misunderstood my question. I do know how to apply styles to xml-document, I am wondering is it possible to apply it to the document, and keep all tags visible